# How to get all values from a String?

Tags: java, android, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to use Firebase smart replies ML kit to generate responses for text. And i would like update my textview with all three responses. I already set up my UI and generated the responses how do i retrieve all three responses to populate my textview? I only manage to get one.

```
public void respondToText(){
        FirebaseSmartReply smartReply = FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getSmartReply();
        smartReply.suggestReplies(conversation)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SmartReplySuggestionResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(SmartReplySuggestionResult result) {
                        if (result.getStatus() == SmartReplySuggestionResult.STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGE) {
                            // The conversation's language isn't supported, so the
                            // the result doesn't contain any suggestions.
                        } else if (result.getStatus() == SmartReplySuggestionResult.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                            // Task completed successfully
                            for (SmartReplySuggestion suggestion : result.getSuggestions()) {

                                String replyText = suggestion.getText();

                                respongeOne.setText(replyText);
                                responeTwo.setText(responseArray.indexOf(0));
                                responseThree.setText(responseArray.indexOf(2));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Task failed with an exception
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`result.getSuggestions()` returns a list of suggested responses, so you can access those suggestions by index:

```
responseOne.setText(result.getSuggestions().get(0).getText());
responseTwo.setText(result.getSuggestions().get(1).getText());    
responseThree.setText(result.getSuggestions().get(2).getText());
```